# Moebius transform unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have the following complex function
$$w=f(z)=\frac{2z+4\mathrm{i}}{2z-2\mathrm{i}}$$
The question is the mapping of the unit circle. I tried to set $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$ and calculate the result but it was not helpful. My next step was to split the complex exponential to its real and imaginary part but I can not determine the map of a circle. The result should be $$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=(\frac{3}{2})^2$$
Does anyone know how to calculate this?

Comment: Note that @JoseCarlosSantos'  answer suggests that the image contains a point at infinity, while your purported solution is a circle. Only one of these can be correct. In particular, $ (1 + 0i)$ is a point on the purported solution. Is there a number $z$ with $\frac{2z + 4i}{2z - 2i} = 1 + 0i$?

Comment: i couldn't show how but the result that you provide is wrong, the right result is a line (i also test it with graphing tool). See JoseCarlosSantos answer, the infinite at i "proves it", always when mapping circunferences with moebius transform and one point is infinite then is a mapping from circunference to a straight line. Since complex number (as polar plotting) is good for polar functions, when a straight line must be modeled by the equations, you will get a little understandable formula for a line. I simplified as much as i could but never looks like a line formula.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 
$$
w=f(z)=\frac{2z+4\mathrm{i}}{2z-2\mathrm{i}}
$$
we can solve for  $z = x + iy$ in terms of $w = u + iv$. I'm going to let you do that part. (Hint: matrix inversion is one way to get to the result), producing something that looks like

$$
z = x + iy = \frac{Aw+B}{Cw+D}
$$
for the inverse function. You then know that you want to find all $w$ for which this point $z$ is on the unit circle, i.e., for which $z\bar{z} = 1$. That amounts to saying that
$$
\left( \frac{Aw+B}{Cw+D} \right) \overline{\left( \frac{Aw+B}{Cw+D}\right)} = 1
$$
which you can write out in terms of $u$s and $v$s and do the multiplication, etc. to get an equation in $u$ and $v$ that $w$ must satisfy.

I haven't done all the algebra for you, because ... well, it's *your* problem, and doing the algebra will give you time to reflect on what you're actually computing.

Small warning: it's just possible that in the course of doing the algebra, you'll find yourself cancelling something like $\frac{3u + 4v}{3u + 4v}$ to get $1$. That's an OK thing to do...except that $3u + 4v$ might be zero. So the equation that you get for $u$ and $v$ might actually miss some $w$ that really does produce a point on the unit circle in $z$. If that happens, you should probably ask yourself "What happened in the algebra, and how does that match what happened in the geometric picture of things?"

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\frac{2z+4i}{2z-2i}=\frac{z+2i}{z-i}=1+\frac{3i}{z-i}.$$So, see what's the image of the unit circle under $z\mapsto\dfrac{3i}{z-i}$ (problem: $i$ belongs to the unit circle) and add $1$ to that.

Comment: This was not really my question. My question was how to get the map of the unit circle when the above function is applied to them.

Comment: @Christoph I thought that you wanted to determine the image of the unit circle under the map $f$, that is, the set $\{f(z)\,|\,z\in S^1\}$. If that is not what you want, then *what* do you want? Please don't say “how to get the map of the unit circle when the above function is applied to them”, because I don't know what that means.

Comment: This is very difficult for me to explain in english, but I try. I want to put the unit circle into the function $f$. I want to see what the function does with all the point. So I tried to put $e^{it}$ into the function but I want to know how to get to the equation of the circle. I don't know how to get the equation of a circle from $1+\frac{3i}{z-i}$.

Comment: It's possible that OP is asking "how do I determine the implicit equation for the result of transforming all points that satisfy some implicit equation", i.e., 
"How do I get from $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to that thing at the bottom of the question with all the $1/2$s in it?"

Comment: @JohnHughes This is exactly what I want to know.

Comment: Great. Then follow the instructions in my answer, and you'll know it.

Comment: This answer is really fast formulation, helping with moebius decomposition in rotation,translation,()... this show a circunference shifted -1 in y-axis (-i), then inverted get a line y=0.5i, multiplied by i is a pi/2 rotation so line at x=-0.5, scale by 3 then line at x=-1.5, finally translation +1 then line at x=-0.5